# How do you implement the big scrollbar in android

Tags: android, user-interface, scrollbar

Does anybody know how you create the that big scrollbar which is used in the contact list? Or the one down there in the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Helpful for all using a Scrollview: fastScrollEnabled only works for Listviews but not for Scrollviews. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164577/how-to-do-fastscrollenabled-like-listview-in-scrollview

Answer (score 7):

Set android:fastScroll="true" on your listview, or anything scrollable by all accounts. You can also set this in your theme or settings.xml files.

My bad,

```
android:fastScrollEnabled
```

As per the comment below.

> On api target >= 11 you should also use
>   list.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true). Otherwise it may not show up. –
>   Igor Ganapolsky

Comment: I guess that was not it: `error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'fastScroll' in package 'android'`

Comment: Well, compiles. But make no difference. At least not with `ScrollView`. Could it be that `ScrollView` does not hava a fast-scroll?

Comment: On api target >= 11 you should also use list.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true).  Otherwise it may not show up.

Answer (score 2):

if you want scroll bar only for a Activity then use

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
```

only for that activity, you can also use this for whole application.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
android:fastScrollEnabled
```