# How to do 'fastScrollEnabled' like ListView in ScrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview

I need fast scroll thumb **in ScrollView** (which we can scroll by dragging the thumb, like in fastScrollEnabled ListView). Problem detail: The list are rows composed with different TypeFace and alignment.

Row 1:
TextView1 (TypeFace:A & LeftAligned)
TextView2 (TypeFace:B & RightAligned)

Row 2:
TextView3 (TypeFace:A & LeftAligned)
TextView4 (TypeFace:B & RightAligned)
.
.
.

Second requirement: I need to be alerted when the view scrolled, including new scroll position - which is implemented by overriding `onScrollChanged` method of the ScrollView.

So I use ScrollView cause I though its impossible to implement using ListView.

Suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ScrollView doesn't support fast scroll (unless you do it yourself of course.) However, what you are describing can be achieved with ListView. ListView lets you use several types of views for the list items.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I've implement it with ListView. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Romain for your answer. Could you explain us why android:fastScrollEnabled is available in ListView (from Android 1.5) and not in ScrollView ? A default of Google engineers ? ;-)

Comment: Because the way the fast scroller works is not really compatible with how scrollview works.